# Why do we require a continuous volatility calibration while pricing Options

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, finance, stochastic-volatility

On pricing Options the volatility surface is represented by a mathematical model (with parameters).

- What does it mean to calibrate the volatility surface
- How often has the volatility surface to be calibrated
- What factors determine when the volatility surface to be calibrated

I know about the volatility smile graph (implied volatility vs strike price for a particular expiry), I would assume this graph can be mathematically represented by a spline with anchor points

With this in mind, what does it mean to 'calibrate the volatility surface' ? - Does it mean we would have to change anchor points based off updated market data (option prices in the market used to calculate the new implied volatility) ?

Comment: A volatility surface is like a weather map (a mathematical representation of a real world phenomenon). A weather map has to be constantly updated because the weather changes and we are unable to accurately determine those changes from mathematical modeling alone (at least not with sufficient accuracy).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I will update my question with additional specifics.

Comment: Since this question has been marked as off-topic; since its deemed as a 'basic financial question'.

Any suggestions on where I can post this question, with someone providing an answer.